# Mysql Query for IF condition and Group by

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT      ps.job_no, ps.booking_no,
            ps.type,ps.shipped_by, ps.invoice_no,
            ps.transporters_id,ps.clients_id,ps.return_terminal,
            ps.destinations_id,ps.forwarder_name,              
            containers.container_size,containers.container_no,
            containers.truck_no,
            ps.driver_cell_no,ps.shipping_line_name,
            containers.cro_no,vessels.vessel_name,vessels.eta,
            containers.empty_pickup_point,containers.loading_point,
            ps.particular 
  FROM      planning_sheet AS ps 
                LEFT JOIN vessels 
                    ON vessels.bookingno= ps.booking_no
                LEFT JOIN containers 
                    ON containers.bookingno = ps.booking_no
GROUP BY ps.clients_id
```

i am new in build such complex queries , the query is defined below, i want a all record against "clients_id" in this query i get one record against this query.

and i also want when "type = 0 then write "Air" or "type =1 than write "Sea"" in the columns of "type".

Answer (score 1):

You have to Aggregate some columns first before using `GROUP BY` clause. **[See Here for some Aggregate functions.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)** But in the case that you want to modify the output in the `type`, you can use inLine `Case` statement.

```
SELECT  ....,
        CASE ps.`type`
           when 0 then 'Air'
           when 1 then 'Sea'
        END as `type`,
        ....
FROM    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put this into your query

```
select
CASE type 
      when '0' then 'Air'
      when '1' then 'Sea'
END as type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT      ps.job_no, ps.booking_no,
            ps.type,ps.shipped_by, ps.invoice_no,
            ps.transporters_id,ps.clients_id,ps.return_terminal,
            ps.destinations_id,ps.forwarder_name,              
            containers.container_size,containers.container_no,
            containers.truck_no,
            ps.driver_cell_no,ps.shipping_line_name,
            containers.cro_no,vessels.vessel_name,vessels.eta,
            containers.empty_pickup_point,containers.loading_point,
            ps.particular ,
           CASE ps.type when '0' then 'Air'
when '1' then 'Sea'
END as type
  FROM      planning_sheet AS ps 
                LEFT JOIN vessels 
                    ON vessels.bookingno= ps.booking_no
                LEFT JOIN containers 
                    ON containers.bookingno = ps.booking_no
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT      ps.job_no, ps.booking_no,
            CASE ps.type WHEN 0 THEN 'Air' WHEN 1 THEN 'Sea' ELSE 'None' END 
            as PLAN_TYPE,
            ps.shipped_by, ps.invoice_no,
            ps.transporters_id,ps.clients_id,ps.return_terminal,
            ps.destinations_id,ps.forwarder_name,              
            containers.container_size,containers.container_no,
            containers.truck_no,
            ps.driver_cell_no,ps.shipping_line_name,
            containers.cro_no,vessels.vessel_name,vessels.eta,
            containers.empty_pickup_point,containers.loading_point,
            ps.particular 
  FROM      planning_sheet AS ps 
                LEFT JOIN vessels 
                    ON vessels.bookingno= ps.booking_no
                LEFT JOIN containers 
                    ON containers.bookingno = ps.booking_no
```

Use According to data type of `ps.type`

`CASE ps.type WHEN 0 THEN 'Air' WHEN 1 THEN 'Sea' ELSE 'None' END`

OR

`CASE ps.type WHEN '0' THEN 'Air' WHEN '1' THEN 'Sea' ELSE 'None' END`